# How does a fully opened ziplock bag hold more food than a flat ziplock bag?

Tags: geometry

> How does a fully opened ziplock bag hold more food than a flat ziplock bag?

I was told the as long as the edges added up to the same perimeter, the area would remain the same. What am I not understanding?

Comment: I can't tell what you have in mind. Actual food takes up volume, not area.  Where did you get the question?

Comment: Isn’t volume just multiples of the same area stacked on each other, so volume wouldn’t just be area multiplied by it’s height and, therefore, the same thing?

Comment: opened bag may have more height than flat bag

Comment: I'm trying to understand this question better. Are you asking about the theoretical food holding capacity of both bags with out allowing the bags to change shape? Or are we allowed to change the shape of the bag? Or is this like a riddle of finding an opaque bag that you know is filled with food in the forest?

Comment: What I am asking is if total area does not change regardless of the shape of the perimeter(not changing length), why does changing the shape of the ziplock bag’s surface area (since surface area is area *height ) change the volume of the bag allowing it to hold more?

Comment: Because the opening allow for "stretching" thus the total volume increases - more food in open bag

Comment: An open ziplock bag is closer to a sphere than a closed flat ziplock bag. A sphere has the most volume if the surface area is the same. Not to mention that the opening counts as extra surface area.

Comment: What gives a sphere more volume than a square?

Comment: A square does not have any volume...

Comment: Sorry, I meant cube. How does a sphere have more volume than a cube/how does a circle have more volume than a square?

Comment: It's explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface-area-to-volume_ratio